# cellForRowAtIndexPath returning nil for custom cell class

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I did the exact same method for another table view that used custom cells in my application, but when I try to cast the cell it returns nil when I cast it as my custom class, but it does not return nil when I do not try to cast the cell. I seem to be doing everything correctly I registered the class for cell reuse and everything.

```
//Register class for cell reuse
    self.table.registerClass(ChatTableViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)

func changeTextForCell(str: String, indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var cell: ChatTableViewCell! = self.table.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as ChatTableViewCell
}
```

^^ returns nil for cell

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell : ChatTableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellId) as? ChatTableViewCell

    if cell == nil {
        cell = ChatTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellId)
    }

    changeTextForCell("something", indexPath: indexPath)

    cell!.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

    if self.messages[indexPath.row].sender == PFUser.currentUser().username {
        cell!.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.737, blue: 0.831, alpha: 1)
        cell!.userImageView.image = UIImage()
        cell!.userImageView.layer.borderWidth = 0
        cell!.chatText.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
    }

    if self.messages[indexPath.row].sender != PFUser.currentUser().username {
        cell!.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0.251, blue: 0.506, alpha: 1)
        cell!.userImageView.image = UIImage.imageWithImage(UIImage(named: "snorlax.png"), newSize: CGSizeMake(cell!.height!, cell!.height!))
        cell!.userImageView.layer.borderWidth = 2
        cell!.userImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        cell!.chatText.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
    }

    cell!.chatText.text = "\(self.messages[indexPath.row].text)"

    return cell!
}


class ChatTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
var chatText: UILabel!
var userImageView: UIImageView!
var height: CGFloat?

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    var size = self.contentView.frame.size

    self.chatText = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(55, 14, 257, 21))
    self.chatText.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    self.chatText.numberOfLines = 0
    self.chatText.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.chatText.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14)
    self.chatText.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
    self.chatText.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight)
    self.contentView.addSubview(self.chatText)

    self.height = 39
    self.userImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(8, 5, self.height!, self.height!))
    self.userImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    self.userImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    self.userImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.height! / 2
    self.contentView.addSubview(userImageView)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

}

Comment: You should never create cell manually if you register cell class.

Comment: Second: use de queue method that also takes index path.

Comment: When i use the deque method some of the cells disappear in the table could there be any reason for this?

Comment: Did you stop creating cell manually?

Comment: Yeah i deleted that line, and I ran the code without the function calling cellForRowAtIndexPath and it worked correctly, however when I put the line back in and used the deque method the table got messed up and cells were deleted.

Comment: Cool, can you make a screenshot and post it here to see what you mean?

Comment: Did you make this custom cell in code or in IB? If the latter, you should not register the class.

Comment: Here is the imgur link... http://imgur.com/a/Lz3Bo  The blank spaces are the spaces where cells should be

Comment: I made the custom cell using code i shall  put the custom cell class in the post

Comment: What is `changeTextForCell` supposed to achieve?  Currently you call  that method in the middle of your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, and `changeTextForCell` then asks the tableView for the cellAtIndexPath.  But the table can't have a cell for that row, because your  `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method hasn't yet returned a value.  Hence you get `nil` (it could be worse, you could have had an infinite loop!).  Pass `cell` as a parameter to `changeTextForCell` rather than using `indexPath` to try to look it up.

Comment: Oh yeah that doesn't really do anything, I was just testing that because when I called cellForRowAtIndex in the heightForRowAtIndex function i was getting nil, so this was just a test method to see if cellForRowAtIndex was working. So do you think I should call a method and pass cell into the method in order to change the cell height, because the built in function is not working?

Comment: No, use `heightForRowAtIndexPath` but I would try to decouple it from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` (because `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is sometimes called before the cell is created - hence you will have nil problems again).  If your height will vary depending on the data to be presented in the cell, use the data (if necessary with proxy UIControls) to determine the height.